# Keyboard control of radio buttons made with JQuery UI Buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button, jquery-ui-button

The JQuery UI Buttons plugin seems to meet all my needs for replacing radio buttons, except that I lose keyboard control. Is there a way to tab between different sets of radio buttons and use the arrow keys to navigate which one is selected, just like normal radio buttons?

This example shows a buttonset() along with regular radio buttons. I can use the keyboard on the regular radio buttons, but not with the buttonset:
http://jsbin.com/udowo3/2

Am I missing something, or does keyboard control just not work with UI buttonsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd, I thought that keyboard navigation was supported, but I guess not. There is a [ticket](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5210) to fix it.

But in the mean time, if you need another option, you can try [this plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/checkbox-radiobutton/):

Comment: thanks, I also thought this was already supported, but I guess not. I'll look at the patch in the ticket you reference. The other plugin won't work because I need them to look like buttons for the UI.